# Regex string matching everything not wrapped

Tags: regex, match

I´m having some trouble with my regex searches. I have been searching for a solution for a while now, and i can´t seem to find the solution to my problem.

I have the following string:

```
1+[2/3]-23+2+<3,4,[22/7]+2;2,3,4>+2
```

I want to match everything not wrapped in [] or <>. So in this string i would get the following matches:

```
1+
-23+2+
+2
```

I tried a lot of different things. The last thing i tried was

```
/[\]>]?.*[\[<]?/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In This Situation, Splitting is Easier than Matching**

Use this regex to split the string:

```
\[[^\]]*\]|<[^>]*>
```

You will get exactly the array you want.

**In JavaScript:**

```
result = str.split(/\[[^\]]*\]|<[^>]*>/);
```

**Explanation**

- Matching all and splitting are two sides of the same coin. By splitting, you remove what you don't want, and you are left with what you want.
- `\[[^\]]*\]` matches complete `[braces]`: an opening brace, then `[^\]]*` any number of chars that are not a closing brace, then a closing brace.
- OR `|`
- likewise, `<[^>]*>` matches complete `<tags>`

Comment: I forgot to add, i´m doing this in Javascript. Will this work in javascript? Because i haven´t seen those signs before

Comment: Yes, it will work in JS. Added JS code for that. :) Writing explanation now.