# Can I use a regex to remove "any whitespace that is not between quotes"?

Tags: java, regex, string, removing-whitespace

*[Regex string matching everything not wrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506932/regex-string-matching-everything-not-wrapped)* covered the task of retrieving characters outside distinct delimiters, but is **it possible to do the same for equal delimiters?**

In other words, I know a regex can match the text between two delimiters that are not the same character (i.e. `>` and `<`), but **can one match text that's *not* between two equal delimiters (i.e. `"` and `"`).**

### Example:

Before:

```json
{ "my key name":
      "my key value",
"foo": ["bar", "baz"]  }
```

After removing whitespace not between quotes:

```json
{"my key name":"my key value","foo":["bar","baz"]}
```

So far, [this is the only regex I've hacked together that does anything similar at all](https://regex101.com/r/t8RtyS/1), but even then it doesn't do it all, and I'm sure I missed some things:

```regex
/(\s+?(?={))|(^\s+)|(\r|\n)|((?=[\[:,])\s+)/gm
```

Comment: so is it not working? In what language are you doing it?

Comment: If your code isn't working, please explain in what ways it is deficient.

Comment: What you have is a normal JSON object.

Comment: @user3218114 Yes, Java

Comment: @ScottHunter it's long and not guaranteed to work, also too specialized

Comment: @hjpotter92 yes, I know. I'm using this to practice making a language parser/tokenizer in Java

Comment: @Supuhstar: "not guaranteed to work" suggests you have examples of it not working; please provide them.  Your other complaints do not address it "not working".

Comment: @ScottHunter For instance, in the ReFiddle I linked, it doesn't remove whitespace after colons or commas.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the idea is: match a whitespace, followed by any number of 1) quoted strings or 2) non-quotes up to the end.

Example in python:

```
import re

text = """
{ "my key name":
      "my key value",
"foo": ["b a r", "b a z"]  }
"""

rx = r"""(?x)
    \s
    (?=
        (
            " [^"]* "
            |
            [^"]
        ) *
        $
    )
"""

print re.sub(rx, '', text)
# {"my key name":"my key value","foo":["b a r","b a z"]}
```

I see the java tag has been added... I don't know java, but the portable form of the above regex

```
\s(?=("[^"]*"|[^"])*$)
```

should work there too.

Comment: OP is looking for regex in **Java** language.

Comment: Why only double quotes are considered. will it work for any non equal delimiters ?

Comment: @user3218114 I can adapt a solution to another language as long as the regex parsers are similar enough. Also, it's only double-quotes here, but can easily be changed by replacing the regex's quotes with some other character

Comment: This is compact and a good idea. Wouldn't add `+` quantifier to white-space? `\s+(?=`... or should it replace only one space, if there several?

Comment: @Jonny5: in this case (just remove ws) - yes, `+` is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this  *(use dot-all modifier, or throw in (?s) at the start of regex)*
Find:

```
raw:     ("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")|(\s+)
quoted:  "(\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\")|(\\s+)"
```

Replace:

```
$1
```

Output:

```
{"my key name":"my key value","foo":["bar","baz"]}
```

Expanded

```
   # ("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")|(\s+)

   (                             # (1 start)
        "
        [^"\\]* 
        (?: \\ . [^"\\]* )*
        "
   )                             # (1 end)
|  
   ( \s+ )                       # (2)
```

Comment: That's pretty elegant! I like it!